# HAProxy, PGSQL with SSL and multiple clusters under single port

Tags: postgresql, haproxy

In my use case I'm using SSL to connect to the PG nodes, since I do not want to have SSL termination, I'm locked in to use TCP mode.

With TCP mode, I have no access to the header information, especially host. Because of this I can not use something like

```
# Primary - RW
frontend PGSQL_primary
    bind *:5432

    acl host_pglab hdr(host) -i pglab-db.local
    acl host_stage hdr(host) -i stage-db.local

    use_backend cluster_pglab-primary if host_pglab
    use_backend cluster_stage-primary if host_stage

backend cluster_pglab-primary
    option httpchk OPTIONS /master
    http-check expect status 200
    default-server inter 2s fall 2 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server pglab-db-01 pglab-db-01.local:5432 maxconn 100 check check-ssl verify none port 8008
    server pglab-db-02 pglab-db-02.local:5432 maxconn 100 check check-ssl verify none port 8008

backend cluster_stage-primary
    option httpchk OPTIONS /master
    http-check expect status 200
    default-server inter 2s fall 2 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server pglab-db-01 stage-db-01.local:5432 maxconn 100 check check-ssl verify none port 8008
    server pglab-db-02 stage-db-02.local:5432 maxconn 100 check check-ssl verify none port 8008
```

From client connect to port 5432 and redirect the traffic to either *pglab* or *stage* cluster's primary node, depending on the hostname.

Is there some alternative to this, that I can avoid using new port for every cluster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll probably need a protocol-aware proxy like [pgbouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/) or [pgpool](https://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Of the two I should think that pgbouncer is closer to haproxy in intention and usage.